# more on converting a c++ lambda to a c function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers, word-wrap

**update 2**

Okay, figured out the second problem. As was pointed out before, I had a conflicting error in terms of trying to match `ReturnType(Args...)` against `ReturnType (*)(Args..)`. The obvious fix is to do:

```
template <typename F, F *fn>
void doSomething() {
    function_helper<F>::template toNative<fn>();
}
```

and it now compiles under clang++.

**update**

As was pointed out, I had a problem with my previous code, where I was trying to pass a function parameter to a template parameter. However, this was hidden by the stranger error of the parse error. Incorrectly passing the function parameter should not have resulted in the error I saw.

It turns out the problem was the new syntax to call a templated member function of a class (see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/keyword_template_qualifier.htm).

The correct syntax should be:

```
template <typename F, F *fn>
void doSomething() {
  native_function native = function_helper<decltype(fn)>::template toNative<fn>();
}
```

where *template* has to be inserted between the '::' and function.

Unfortunately this is a very difficult problem search for as: (a) the compiler error is completely unhelpful, and (b) there was no obvious search term to use.

Also, this currently doesn't seem to work under the current version of clang++, nor g++ 4.6 (so far I either get another syntax error or internal compiler error).

**original question**

In a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545537/converting-a-c-lambda-to-a-c-function), I have the following code:

```
template <typename T>
struct function_helper {};

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_helper<ReturnType(Args...)> {

    // wraps actual function in a native-c function (allow it to be called
    // via an external scripting language API) 
    template <ReturnType (*fn)(Args...)>
    static native_function toNative() {
         return [](State *state) -> int {
            Context ctx(state);
            return apply_helper<sizeof...(Args)>::apply(ctx, fn);
        };
    }
};
```

which I would like to wrap with:

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
native_function function_(Context &ctx, const std::string &name, ReturnType (*fn)(Args...)) {
    ctx.registerFn(name, function_helper<decltype(fn)>::toNative<fn>());
}
```

However, this gives me a 'Parse Error'. If I don't try to wrap it in a function, but instead do:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // ...
    ctx.registerFn("myFunc", function_helper<decltype(myFunc)>::toNative<myFunc>());
}
```

everything compiles and runs correctly. Likewise, if I used a macro, it also works. However, for design reasons, I'd much rather use a function.

I've additionally tried a slightly different formulation, with the same results:

```
template <typename T>
struct function_args {};

template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
struct function_args<ReturnType (*)(Args...)> {
    const int size = sizeof...(Args);
};

template <typename F, F *fn>
native_function wrap() {
    return [](State *state) -> int {
        Context ctx(state);
        return apply_helper<function_args<decltype(fn)>::size>::apply(ctx, fn);
    };
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is it a compiler issue? The parse error makes me suspicious that it's the compiler at fault.

I could get rid of the parse error by adding a parameter to toNative(). However, this just caused a different error that there was no such method toNative(int).

I'm using the latest clang++ that comes with xcode (based on LLVM 3.1svn).

Comment: Here is the same question from 2009: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.lang.c++.moderated/lLbhqeymFJ0 . Obviously, decltype takes the place of BOOST_TYPEOF, but the only solution at least at that time was to use a macro.

Comment: `decltype(fn)` should be a function pointer type, which doesn't match your partial specialization. You can try `decltype(*fn)` instead. I have no idea if this is your actual problem though.

Comment: `fn` is a function parameter, it can't be used as a template argument. Additionally, `decltype(fn)` is `ReturnType(*)(Args...)`, which won't be matched by your partial specialization. Just use `function_helper<ReturnType(Args...)>` instead, though this won't help because of my first sentence.

Comment: @Xeo Yup, good point. I should've caught that. Any suggestions on how to get around this, or am I stuck with a macro? Also, if you put your comment as a an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: If you mean not having to specify the function type in some way, then alas, no, there is no way other than a macro.

Comment: Okay, good to know. One more question: if I do something like `#define wrap(fn) (function_helper<decltype(fn)>::toNative<fn>())`, and then use it like: `template <typename F, F *fn> void method() { wrap(fn); }` I still get a parse error. However, fn is a template parameter now. Is that still expected? I've tested wrap, and it works outside of that function call.